# NullPointerException thrown after field is check if it is null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bukkit

I am developing a plugin for Bukkit (http://bukkit.org) and after verifying that it is not null, it gives me a NullPointerException at the 2nd line

```
    String description = getConfig().getString("core.commands."+cmd+".description");
    if (!(description.isEmpty()))
          getCommand(cmd).setDescription(description);
    else 
          getLogger().warning("NO description assigned to: " + cmd);
    description = null;
```

Comment: Verifying that *what* isn't null? You're verifying that `description` isn't *empty* - but if it's a null reference, that `isEmpty` call will throw. Or maybe `getCommand` returns null. Spacing your code out would make it easier to see where the error is - *and* make it much easier to read your code in general.

Comment: I already tried if (description != null)

Comment: And have you tried formatting the code more sensibly so that you can check whether it's the `if` condition or the resulting statement which throws the exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

`isEmpty()` is different from `null` check. `isEmpty()` checks is `String` is empty `String` (which means `""`).

You need to do something like

```
if (description != null && !description.isEmpty())
```

Comment: @stasiomod: Please update question with full exception stack.

Comment: Also, etiquette thing, but all caps implies yelling. Please don't yell at us. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code `!(description.isEmpty())` doesn't verify that `description` is not null.  For that you need `description != null`.

Your test should be:

```
if (description != null && !description.isEmpty()) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem *isn't* in the `if` condition - but in the statement that follows. I would *start* by reformatting the code like this:

```
String description = getConfig().getString("core.commands." + cmd + ".description");
if (!description.isEmpty())
{
    getCommand(cmd).setDescription(description);
}
else
{
    getLogger().warning("NO description assigned to: " + cmd);
}
```

(I've removed the `description = null;` statement as it's almost certainly unnecessary.)

With that change, you'll be able to tell more about what's throwing the exception. You can go further:

```
String description = getConfig().getString("core.commands." + cmd + ".description");
if (!description.isEmpty())
{
    Command command = getCommand(cmd); // Or whatever type it is
    command.setDescription(description);
}
else
{
    getLogger().warning("NO description assigned to: " + cmd);
}
```

Aside from anything else, when you now step through the code in a debugger (assuming that's even feasible) you'll be able to tell whether `command` is null (which I suspect it is). If you can't use a debugger, you could at least add logging.

(Others have already suggested checking whether `description` is `null`, but it sounds like that isn't the problem, which is why I've suggested that the problem could be within the body of the `if` statement.)

Comment: Ja... I realized that it is the problem of the getCommand().ANYTHING(); So now i get to play the waiting game until the devs of this API fix it...

Comment: @stasiomod: Well that just means that `getCommand()` returns `null` - so you should look at *why* it's returning `null`. Perhaps your `cmd` variable doesn't have a suitable value?